# multiple ip replacement in different commands in a file

Tags: python

I have following set of commands stored in a file

```
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr <ip> adv <ip> 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr <ip> self-originate 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr <ip>
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr adv <ip> 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr orig 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr
```

Need to replace above set of commands with this :-

```
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr 222.0.0.1 adv 10.0.0.1 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr 222.0.0.1 self-originate 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr 100.0.0.1 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr adv 50.0.0.1 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr orig 
ip ospf db area 0.0.0.0 rtr
```

Can some one suggest a way to do this? All ips are different, there are lot more commands of these type. Whole file has to be parsed and ips need to be replaced with proper values.

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish which <ip> tag needs to be replace by which IP address?

Comment: No, <ip> is common for all the commands, so cant perform global search and replace, too.

Answer (score 1):

As DarinDouglass said, you need to have a way to distinguish between the IPs. If the file has a fixed format and you want to replace the first occurrence of `<ip>` with a certain IP, the second with another IP and so on, here's what you can do:

```
import re

def replacer(l):
    i = iter(l)
    replace = lambda x: i.next()
    return replace

# example usage:
print re.sub("e", replacer(["1", "2", "3"]), "This is a sentence")

# prints "This is a s1nt2nc3"
```

`re.sub` accepts a custom function that returns a string. `replacer` returns a function that when called, returns the next element in the list `l`.

I can help you out more if you give additional details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ordered list of ip address:

```
ip_token = "<ip>" # your ip positionning substring
ip_list  = ["127.0.0.1","127.0.0.2",...] # your ip list

with open("myfile","r+") as f:
    old = f.read()
    f.seek(0)

    #loop through file content
    for line in old:
        modified_line = line

        #replace the tokens by the ips
        while "<ip>" in modified_line:
            modified_line = modified_line.replace(ip_token,ip_list.pop(0),1)

        f.write(modified_line)
```

Comment: seeing this error even after including #! in first line, `python2.5 ipstuff.py
ipstuff.py:6: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "ipstuff.py", line 6
    with open("myfile.txt","r+") as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: well this was Python 2.7, not 2.5. You can translate it easily

Answer (score 0):

Store ips as a list of tuples. Each tuple represents a line, and each IP in the tuple represents the order in which IPs are to be replaced.

Then traverse through your file.

For each line, fetch its position in the file with `enumerate`, find the position of `<ip>` and replace it with the tuple you fetch from the list of tuples using the index.

If there is no element for that index in your list of tuples, it means you have nothing to replace.

The problem with this approach is that you need to have as many items in your list of tuples as lines, and this is wasteful if the file you intend to replace with is large. To avoid this, you can use a dictionary where the key is the line number and the value is the tuple representing the IPs to be replaced.